# Printer and software for label printing?

Tags: xubuntu, printing

I'm looking for a printer to print on adhesive product labels like these: http://www.onlinelabels.com/OL996.htm?src=dlc-28

Are most printers compatible with Ubuntu?

Also what would be a good software to use for designing and printing the labels?

Comment: This is not the right place for shopping recommendations according to our help http://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic Regarding printers compatibility there is a website for that: https://www.openprinting.org

Comment: See also here http://askubuntu.com/questions/30962/good-business-card-creation-software for alternatives.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Libreoffice has label printing capabilities. Just open File - New - Labels.

Any good printer which is Linux compatible should do. You can check [here](https://www.openprinting.org/printers) and [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/HardwareSupportComponentsPrinters) if the printer you're considering is compatible.

As a side note, I recommend using good quality label paper, because if labels get stuck in the printer, they can cause havoc.

Comment: +1 for Libreoffice, thanks!  I had been having no luck with Gimp